# Why is my setTimeout with generator function not firing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a nested `yield call` which I want to fire a timer in my saga. For some reason however, the timer isn't firing and `showModal` isn't being called. Any idea why this is?

```
function* showModal() {
  yield put(showPermissionsNeededWall('Please sign in', null));
  readTimeLoginBoxShown();
}

export default function* showPermissionWall() {
  yield takeLatest(SHOW_TIMED_LOGIN_WALL, function* () {
    const { auth } = yield select(state => state);

    if (!auth.currentUser) {
      // yield showModal(); // works

      yield call(setTimeout, function* () {
        yield showModal(); // never fires
      }, 1000 * SHOW_LOGIN_WALL_AFTER_IN_SECONDS);
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you have to call your `showModal` generator function directly with `call` or you should `put` that action which will trigger your `showModal` with the help of `takeLatest`.

So, each time you want to call `showModal`:

```
yield call(showModal);
```

In the other hand, in saga context you should use `delay` from `redux-saga/effects`.
In this case I would use this:

```
yield call(delay, 1000 * SHOW_LOGIN_WALL_AFTER_IN_SECONDS);
yield call(showModal);
```

All of it together:

```
import { call, put, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';

export default function* showPermissionWall() {
  yield takeLatest(SHOW_TIMED_LOGIN_WALL, function* () {
    const { auth } = yield select(state => state);

    if (!auth.currentUser) {
      yield call(delay, 1000 * SHOW_LOGIN_WALL_AFTER_IN_SECONDS);
      yield call(showModal);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks Knight! Much appreciated